# Propagating an event beforehand

Tags: jquery, dom, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I am trying to make an ajax searchbox work but the problem is that the `focusout` event on the INPUT field is triggered before the click event that I make on the anchor elements of response DIV. The `focusout` code empties/hides(both cases) the response DIV and hence click isn't triggered. Is it possible to trigger the propagating click in the `focusout` event code at the start / trigger click before `focusout` / any workaround?

HTML -

```
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" name="searchbox" class="searchbox" placeholder="search.." />
    <div class="search_results">
    </div>
</div>
```

Searchbox JS -

```
$('.searchbox').focusin(function(){
    $(this).css('color','#000');
    $(this).animate({
        'width':'300px',
        'font-size':'16px'
    }, 500);
    if($(this).val()){
        $(this).trigger('keyup');
    }
}).focusout(function(){

    //Is a call to propagation possible here?

    $(this).css('color','#aaa');

    $('.search_results').html('').hide();
    //I am using the `on` method for dynamically added elements in response DIV which works when the above line is commented

    $(this).animate({
        'width':'150px',
        'font-size':'15px'
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: *"The focusout code empties/hides(both cases) the response DIV and hence click isn't triggered"* ?? if you want to click something, why are you removing it before clicking..? why can't you remove it on click..?

Comment: I just want to hide it first(because I have its reference at instant) and then direct the page via click. I don't want to click, go to parent and then hide. Eventually the click is going to propagate, why not do it at convenience?
Though this would do as well. Thank you.